# Forex api в .Net

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core

Добрый день, для практики программирования решил поработать с какой-нибудь торговой платформой, может кто-нибудь может посоветовать апи какой-нибудь торговой платформы, чтобы можно было посредством апи получать курсы,количества транзакий, собирать статистику ? 
Гугление не увеньчалось успехом.
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [TWS API Interactive Brokers](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/#gsc.tab=0)
2. [Barchart OnDemand](https://www.barchart.com/ondemand/api)
3. [Пример использования недокументированного API Google Finance](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221952/Simple-Csharp-DLL-to-download-data-from-Google-Fin)
4. [Hacking Google Finance in Real-Time for Algorithmic Traders](http://www.quantatrisk.com/2015/05/07/hacking-google-finance-in-pre-market-trading-python/)
5. [Currency Feed](http://currencyfeed.com/)
6. [Схожий вопрос на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3928610/4344645)
7. [Схожий вопрос на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527703/how-can-i-get-stock-quotes-using-google-finance-api)